# WaitForSingleObject crashes

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

Here is a code below. The code is not complete, I omitted releasing resources part and implementation of QueryRes logic.

```
#define N 5

/*simply resources manager which has N shared resources*/
class ResourceManager
{
public:
    ResourceManager()
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
              resources[i] = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    }
/*CreateMutex for on resources array in ctor*/
/*CloseHandle() in dtor and ReleaseMutex in another function which is called after QueryRes*/

        void QueryRes(int i)
        {
          WaitForSingleObject(resources[i], INFINITE); //(*) Here is the problem
        }

private:
        HANDLE resources[N];
};

/*User who asks for resource time-to-time*/
class User
{
public:
    User(ResourceManager& res_holder_, int res_num) : resource_holder(resource_holder), resource_to_query(res_num) {}

    void WorkWithResource()
    {
            while(1)
            {
                    resource_holder.QueryRes(resource_to_query);
            }
    }


    static void Run (void* params)
    {
            static_cast<User*>(params)->WorkWithResource();
    }

private:
    ResourceManager& resource_holder;
    int resource_to_query;
};

int main()
{
        ResourceManager resource_manager;
        User* users[5];
        HANDLE threads[5];

        for (size_t i = 0 ; i < 5; ++i)
        {
                users[i] = new User(resource_manager, i % 5);
                threads[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&User::Run, users[i], 0, NULL);
        }
        WaitForMultipleObjects(5, threads, true, INFINITE);


        return 0;
}
```

At (*) place I get an "access violation exception" when the function does `WaitForSingleObject` on already locked mutex.

I also tried

```
 while(WaitForSingleObject(resources[i], INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
```

and got the same result.

Why do I get the exception?

I tried vc 2003, 2008 and 2010. I can't use boost/pthreads/etc.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the value of N used in `ResourceManager`?

Comment: Can you include the declaration of `N` (from `HANDLE resources[N];`).

Comment: You are going to need to show the constructor of `ResourceManager`.

Comment: update: N defined + ctor

Comment: Note this code does not compile due to trailing `)` in `WaitForSingleObject(resources[i], INFINITE));`. Also, `User` constructor does not take 3 arguments.

Comment: If you have to cast to LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE to compile without errors, your signature of the thread function is wrong. The solution is to use the correct signature, not to cast!

Comment: Odds are high that this doesn't crash in WFSO but on accessing the *resources* member.  Bad object pointer or heap corruption for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error lies in the constructor of

> ```
> User(ResourceManager& res_holder_, int res_num) : resource_holder(resource_holder), resource_to_query(res_num)    {   }
> ```

You should have

> ```
> User(ResourceManager& res_holder_, int res_num) : resource_holder(**res_holder_**), resource_to_query(res_num)    {   }
> ```

instead !

Comment: God bless you, man :) I spent a half of my day because of this mistake!

Answer (score 1):

When you get an access violation (or segfault in other platforms, although generically speaking this is a bad pointer dereference), often the reason is obvious from looking at the code...  In this case nothing pops out at me from what you've posted.  My guess based on what you said is something smashed the stack.

However, a bit of advice...  When you see an access violation you can't explain, the first step is not to post to Stack Overflow.  Look at it in a debugger!  If you download "Debugging tools for Windows" from Microsoft and use "windbg", and learn how to use it, it will tell you more about this crash than you ever thought you could know - what the bad address it tried to access was, disassembly of `WaitForMultipleObjects` so you can see what it's doing and where the address came from, etc.  I usually find with a few `k`, `r`, `u`, and `dq` commands in windbg, the cause for a bad pointer dereference becomes pretty obvious.

Comment: I've been looking at my debugger a half of day. Do you debug an winapi function every time it crashes? I thought i just made some well-known mistake or something.

Comment: @fogbit Yes in fact, if I have a crash in a function that's not mine, I do debug it with `u` (disassemble).  For something like an OS or library function usually it means you gave it a bad pointer, i.e. the pointer it faulted on is derived from something you did.  You have to have a holistic view of the machine when debugging crashes like that, all of your layering and abstraction and distinction between your code and APIs should rightfully go out the window.